# SolidWorks URDF exporter does not save limits

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the sw_urdf_exporter installer from http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter and is using it together with SW 2013 edu. on Windows 7

My problem is that the joint limits i set in the joint configuration form is not saved. According to the change log this issue was addressed with V1.0 Build 4699.29466.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

The software is reported as v.1.2.2 on the webpage, the installer reports 1.2.0.0, but the change log seems to imply that it is 1.0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181061/solidworks-urdf-exporter-does-not-save-limits/) by [Karl Damkjær Hansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2205/karl-damkj%C3%A6r-hansen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) on 2014-07-01**:
Do you mean to say that they are not exporting the limits, or they are not saving them to the configuration inside of SW?

**Comment by [Karl Damkjær Hansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2205/karl-damkj%C3%A6r-hansen/) on 2014-07-02**:
Thanks for responding brawner :-)
If I set the limits in the form, they are exported alright, but the limits (nor soft limits of calibration values) are saved to the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all values are saved, yet. The configuration file saves coordinate reference information. In essence, the information that the exporter needs in order to extract proper info from SW each time.

I believe limit mates are respected in the latest version of the exporter. If you want to create an easy export, add limit mates to each joint that represent the limits of the joint itself. I think the soft limits are set to the same thing as the hard limits in the urdf. Create an configuration solely for export with these limit mates unsuppressed if you don't want to deal with them in the future.

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0